# Analyze what compression type use for table

Tags: sql-server, compression

I have SQL Server 2014 database. As size of this database isn't small I want to apply data compression to it. I've used `sp_estimate_data_compression_savings` to check what how many size I can save and I thought that I should apply that compression type where I can save the most, but... I found [this post on msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051(v=sql.100).aspx) where they analyze what type to choose base on 2 more values : `Percent of Scan Operations` and `Percent of Update Operations`.

So now I don't know what to choose.

---

For me it will be more easier if I have same table as in post where they analyze all percentage of compression

Comment: Maybe the best way in your case use a `column-store indexes`

Comment: @Devart, they are supported only in 2016 version, aren't they?

Comment: No :) added from 2012 version

Comment: Why can't you provide values for two counters as per DMVs in article ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar, Do you mean I should run 4 queries (estimate for Page, Row compression and for Scan and Update operations)?

Comment: Yes,in  the article referenced ,there are DMVs which gives you counters of U and  S values and it also states which values are  best,why can't you run them